# Didn't understand Mr. Stroustup's suggestion to delete the copy default and move operations for the abstract class Shape

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to understand what the author suggests in `3.3.4 Suppressing Operations` in his new book (TCPL 4th edition), to no avail.

**Excerpt from book**

> Using the default copy or move for a class in a hierarchy is
>   typically a disaster: Given only a pointer to a base, we simply don’t
>   know what members the derived class has (§3.3.3), so we can’t know how
>   to copy them. So, the best thing to do is usually to delete the
>   default copy and move operations; that is, to eliminate to default
>   definitions of those two operations:

```
class Shape {
public:
    Shape(const Shape&) =delete; // no copy operations
    Shape& operator=(const Shape&) =delete;
    Shape(Shape&&) =delete; //no move operations
    Shape& operator=(Shape&&) =delete;
    ~Shape();
};
```

> Now an attempt to copy a Shape will be caught by the compiler. If you
>   need to copy an object in a class hierarchy, write some kind of clone
>   function (§22.2.4).

For example, the code below doesn't compile with `Shape(const Shape&) = delete;`, as the `clone()` function invokes `Shape`'s copy constructor.

```
#include <iostream>

class Shape
{
    public:
    virtual ~Shape() {}
    Shape() {}
    Shape(const Shape&) {};
    virtual Shape* clone() const = 0;
};

class Circle: public Shape
{
    public:
    Circle(int i) : a(i) {}
    Circle* clone() const { return new Circle(*this); }
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    Shape* p = new Circle(1);
    Shape* q = p->clone();

    std::cout << dynamic_cast<Circle*>(p)->a << std::endl;
    std::cout << dynamic_cast<Circle*>(q)->a << std::endl; 

}
```

Comment: I think the point in deleting the copy constructor is that you cannot rely on the copy constructor of the Shape class to reliably (if at all) copy all data for a derived class? I could be wrong, I don't have the book.

Answer (score 5):

If you only have a pointer to a `Shape`, then you can't possibly make a copy of the actual implementation - it will (most likely) be larger, so your copy will be "sliced". In your example, `Circle` will have an extra `int a`; that isn't part of the `Shape` class - which would be lost if you just plain copy a `Shape` class object without knowing it's a `Circle` (and the whole point of polymorphism is that you are not supposed to "know" what object is what type when dealing with it in generic functions)

To avoid having problems caused by accidentally using something like:

```
*q = *p;
```

it is better to "delete" the operators that will allow you to do that

However, as the copy constructor is needed for the case you describe, so one solution is to make it `protected` - that protects against something other than a derived class using it, and works correctly.

Thanks to robson below (and a nights sleep as well), the solution is clearly to make a copy-constructor in `Circle`. Just because you don't have one for `Shape` doesn't mean that you can't have one in the derived class:

```
class Circle: public Shape
{
    public:
    Circle(int i) : a(i) {}
    Circle(const Circle& other) { a = other.a; }    // Note this line!
    Circle* clone() const { return new Circle(*this); }
    int a;
};
```

The reason it tries to use the `Shape` copy constructor is because you haven't got one in your own class. You should!

You could also do (as Robson explained):

```
class Circle: public Shape
{
    public:
    Circle(int i) : a(i) {}
    Circle* clone() const { return new Circle(a); }
    int a;
};
```

And not need a copy constructor at all. Both of these solutions solve the "you are trying to use a deleted `Shape(const Shape &) constructor`. It really is obvious once you see it.

Comment: But how to handle the clone() function without the default copy constructor for Shape ?

Comment: What help is a copy constructor in `Shape` - you should never copy a `Shape` object, because a pure `Shape` object is not a useful thing to have anyway - you should be copying the `Circle` or `Square` or `Octagon`, that is derived from the `Shape` object - and you do that by using the copy constructor of the derived class - like the `clone` function in `Circle` does.

Comment: In other words, the WHOLE point of deleting the `Shape` copy constructor is to avoid making copies of a `Shape` that isn't really a `Shape` but an `Octagon`. Forcing a compiler error at that point, and hopefully the programmer finds that "Ah, I should use `shape_ptr->clone` here".

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: [Here's an idea.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b51120ee648123b7e4a8448fa635fc74-50d9cfc8a1d350e7409e81e87c2653ba)

Comment: As I said before, without the default copy ctor the code doesn't compile. The expression `new circle(*this)` in the clone function invokes Shape's copy constructor.

Comment: Just making the `Shape` copy constructor a protected function works for this case, and prevents accidental use.

Comment: @Xeo After thinking about your example for a while, I have to agree that your solution solves the problem that I alluded before. But I don't think this was what Mr. Stroustup was thinking when he wrote this section of the book.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil I suspect it's an oversight (just like I oversaw it, even when you mentioned it in the question). But to be sure, you'll have to ask Bjarne, really. There is an errata list for the 3rd printing of the 4th edition, but it doesn't mention it - possibly because nobody ha spotted it yet... http://www.stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html
I was trying to find a place where you could report errors, but either my reading skills are failing me, or it's well hidden (or both)

Comment: @WakeupBrazil You can use some other ctor, like `new Circle(a);` for example.

Comment: @robson3.14 But this a cloning (copying) operation.

Answer (score 1):

He meant that its bad to make them accessible from outside, due to potentioal object slicing problems. It you dont need to make the class clonable than deleting is sufficient, otherwise you can just make it protected to be accessible only within `clone()` and successors.